# SSL connection with TLS connection error

Tags: openssl, curl, tls

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, installed at VirtualBox (Mac) using vagrant. I am not using any proxy server.

In my company network, when I try

```
curl -1vsS https://github.com/FGRibreau/doxx/archive/master.zip
```

I get the following results:

```
* About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)                                                                                           
*   Trying 192.30.252.130... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
```

It stucked at Client hello.
Same goes with other tools I am using e.g. npm, bower

But if I do the following:

```
wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1 https://github.com/FGRibreau/doxx/archive/master.zip
```

I am able to download the file. 
The major issue here is I only get the connection problem if I am in my company network. The problem mentioned never occurred if I connected at other network. (e.g. home, public Internet access, and etc.)

Before I get around the issue by forcing all connections using SSLv3 as the problem only happens if client/server decided to use TLS.

I assume it is because of the recent SSL vulnerability that people starting to disable SSLv3.

Anything I can do to check whats wrong with my setup that causes problem when using TLS for HTTPS connections?

[Edit]
If I do the following command:

```
strace -o ./tmp.out curl -v -sS https://github.com/FGRibreau/doxx/archive/master.zip
```

The tmp.out is too huge to paste it here, so the last few lines are:

```
write(3, "\26\3\1\0\337\1\0\0\333\3\2T`E\30\3006\315\336\220I\6|\v'!8cp*\206\332"..., 228) = 228
write(2, "*", 1)                        = 1
write(2, " ", 1)                        = 1
write(2, "SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hel"..., 40) = 40
read(3, 0x9cdf3e0, 7)                   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {10742, 580346821}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {10742, 580375417}) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 299700) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (To be restarted)
--- SIGINT (Interrupt) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

It seems like is waiting for server to response, but didn't get it and exited with error.

Comment: Problem solved, seems like the sites I am visiting is using Tor, and our network firewall is dropping anything related to Tor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, seems like the sites I am visiting is using Tor, and our network firewall is dropping anything related to Tor.

Just need to remove the firewall rule that is blocking Tor.